# How to run graphql api in php using curl post request

Tags: php, curl, graphql

This is a cURL function that can send or retrieve data. It should work with any PHP app that supports OAuth:

```
function jwt_request($url,$token, $post) {
    header('Content-Type: application/json'); // Specify the type of data
    $ch = curl_init($url); // Initialise cURL
    $post = json_encode($post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // Specify the request method as POS
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); // Set the posted fields
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // This will follow any redirects
    $result = curl_exec($ch); // Execute the cURL statement
    curl_close($ch); // Close the cURL connection
    return ($result); // Return the received data
}
// I am running in localhost
$url = "http://localhost:3000/graphql";
// This is what query i am running
$post = '{"query": "query { login(username:"abbas@gmail.com",password: "abbas") { userID token } }" }';
// This is the function i am using in above
$json = jwt_request($url,$token, $post);
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($json); // here printing
```

Comment: What is the question, exactly?

Comment: I need to run the graphql api on laravel which is a thirday party i wanted to pass header authorization.

Answer (score 0):

After spending so much time and way I came across the best solution for this issues is just use this git repository with the help of the composer, and it works awesome, but you must have some knowledge about the composer and how to install and use the libraries with the help of auto loading useful file.

Here is the link for the repository. They have already give a proper example using OAuth2 provider also.

[GraphQL-Client](https://github.com/softonic/graphql-client)

Hope it helps.

Here is the sample code:

```
<?php
$client = \Softonic\GraphQL\ClientBuilder::build('https://catalog.swarm.pub.softonic.one/graphql');

$query = <<<'QUERY'
query GetFooBar($idFoo: String, $idBar: String) {
  foo(id: $idFoo) {
    id_foo
    bar (id: $idBar) {
      id_bar
    }
  }
}
QUERY;

$variables = [
    'idFoo' => 'foo',
    'idBar' => 'bar',
];
$response = $client->query($query, $variables);
?>
```